# Scheme struct with another struct

Tags: struct, scheme, racket, user-defined-types

I'm trying to learn scheme (drracket) by myself and I encountered a problem.

I'm trying to work with different shapes such as circles , squares and rectangles. 
The task is the following:

"Define the types "circle", "square" and "rectangle" and define the main-type "shape".
I need the shape struct for the next part of the task where I have to define a function "area-of-shape" which gets a "shape"databundle and which is supposed to represent the area of any given shape.

Here is what I have so far:

```
(define-struct square (nw lenght))

(define-struct circle (center radius))

(define-struct rectangle (nw width height))

(define-struct shape (...))



(define (area-of-shape shapeA)
  (cond 
    [(square? (shapeA)) (* (square-lenght shapeA) (square-lenght shapeA))]
    [(circle? (shapeA)) (* 3.14 (* (circle-radius shapeA) (circle-radius shapeA)))]
    [(rectangle? (shapeA)) (* (rectangle-width shapeA) (rectangle-height shapeA))]))
```

How do I define the struct `shape`? I tried something like

`(define-struct shape (circle square rectangle))`

But that wouldn't make any sense since the struct would need all 3 shapes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what do you want that structure for? If I understand correctly. You can pass any variable you define as square circle or rectangle to you function. Also, you seem to have an extra set of parens around your argument`(shapeA)`. This should cause an error by the interpreter.

Comment: Basically i want area of shape to work only (!) with shapes. Not with any other number or something else. So i basically want to give a "shape" into the function and the "shape" should be defined as either a square, a circle or a rectangle. Its a exercise i found online without a solution. The function area-of-shape is not finished. I included it to show what it should do.  I can add the task to make it clearer

Comment: Just as a guidepost, `#lang racket`'s structures are the fundamental building block for the Racket environment. Making them first class in the language definition is one of the big things that makes `racket` different from R5RS Scheme. The magnitude of that decision is reflected in their richness of features and relatively high level of implementation complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Racket structs can inherit from another struct. So:

```
#lang racket

(struct shape ())
(struct square shape (nw length))
(struct circle shape (center radius))
(struct rectangle shape (nw width height))

(define (area-of-shape shape)
  (if (shape? shape)
    (cond
      [(square? shape)    (* (square-length shape) (square-length shape))]
      [(circle? shape)    (* 3.14 (* (circle-radius shape) (circle-radius shape)))]
      [(rectangle? shape) (* (rectangle-width shape) (rectangle-height shape))]
      [else (error 'area-of-shape "Unhandled Shape Condition.")])
    (error 'area-of-shape "Argument not a Shape.")))

;; Example uses
(area-of-shape (square 0 10))
(area-of-shape (circle 0 10))
(area-of-shape (rectangle 0 10 10))
```

By the way, for something like `area-of-shape`, I find it handier to use `match` than `cond`:

```
(define (area-of-shape shape)
  (match shape
    [(square _ len)    (* len len)]
    [(circle _ rad)    (* 3.14 (* rad rad))]
    [(rectangle _ w h) (* w h)]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) That's exactly what I was looking for. I haven't seen "match" before but I will look it up. thanks mate

Comment: I get the following error: define-struct: expected at least one field name (in parentheses) after the structure name, but found something else" because after the name of the struct it expects paranthesis but gets "shape"

Comment: Notice that I'm using `struct`. `define-struct` is an older/legacy form.

Comment: So it's not working with define-struct? Im still working with the setting "intermediate Student with lambda". So it gives me an error saying "struct" is not defined. Even when i change the settings its still giving me the same error

Comment: See the docs for [define-struct](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._define-struct%29%29). It looks like you want the variant of `id-maybe-super` that is `(id super-id)` in parens. So you'd want `(define-struct (square shape) (nw length))` and so on.

Comment: Very nice answer. From the comments and the question I think the OP wants the function to accept only `shape`s. So maybe a test, and error message would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as follows:

```
(define (area-of-shape shapeA)
  (cond 
    [(square?    shapeA) (* (square-lenght shapeA) (square-lenght shapeA))]
    [(circle?    shapeA) (* 3.14 (* (circle-radius shapeA) (circle-radius shapeA)))]
    [(rectangle? shapeA) (* (rectangle-width shapeA) (rectangle-height shapeA))]
    [else (error 'area-of-shape "A shape is either a square, a circle, or, a rectangle")]))
```

Comment: That was my idea as well but it's said that the function area-of-shape has to get something that is a "shape-objekt".  It's stated that i have to define the struct shape.  Sorry for my bad english

Comment: You can simply state as a comment that a shape object is either a square, a circle or a rectangle.